# MobileFirst V6.3 override adapter deployment

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst

I want to know if there is a way to avoid automatic adapter deployment after a service discovery generated wizard execution. Can you help ?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I have generated a new adapter using the Service Discovery wizard. This only generated the adapter - it did not deploy it.

Perhaps you are referring to the auto-deployment after you make a change in your adapter files?
If you are using MobileFirst Platform Foundation 6.3, then you can disable this from the Eclipse preferences > MobileFirst > untick "Automatically Deploy Adapters on Change"